# YouTube Content ID API Manual Claims

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I’ve been doing some research on the YouTube Content ID api and researching about making claims, there is a “manual claim” property, but it’s noted as restricted with semi-minimal information about it.

```
params.isManualClaim - restricted
```

https://gist.github.com/esvit/27bc8f26c09c7a3a0c18

My question is, what does restricted actually mean? Is it restricted to only partners that have access to perform manual claims, or is it restricted to everyone and only available to internal YouTube processes?

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/).

> Note: The YouTube Content ID API is intended for use by YouTube
>   content partners and is not accessible to all developers or to all
>   YouTube users. If you do not see the YouTube Content ID API as one of
>   the services listed in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), see
>   [www.youtube.com/partner](https://www.youtube.com/partner) to learn more about the YouTube Partner
>   Program.
>
> The YouTube Content ID API lets developers build applications that
>   interact directly with YouTube's rights management system. The system,
>   which has an online interface at [www.youtube.com/content_id](https://www.youtube.com/content_id) ,
>   enables content owners and administrators to provide YouTube with
>   metadata, ownership information, and policy information for their
>   assets.
>
> As a YouTube partner, you can use the API to create new assets and
>   manage existing assets. You can also retrieve information about your
>   Content Manager account, including a list of saved policies that you
>   can apply to your claimed content.
>
> In addition, by combining the YouTube Content ID API with the YouTube
>   Data API and YouTube Player APIs, you can enable your application to
>   also upload, manage, and play YouTube videos.

Comment: Yes, I’ve read that but that doesn’t apply to the manual claim flag. I have access to the Content ID API, I’m taking about the manual claim flag (and process), specifically.